# Displaying real-time output from remotely running powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to show output in a local console window from a script which is running on a remote machine.

My script is looking something like this. I have tried `-verbose` flag and `Set-PSDebug -Trace 1` but neither worked.

```
$command = ".\test-custom.ps1"          
$str = '{0} {1} {2} {3} "{4}" {5}' -f ($command, $txtBoxUserName.Text, $pwd, $url, $testScripts, $reportName)
$sb  =  [scriptblock]::Create($str)
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock $sb
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use as job like:

```
$myjob=Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock $sb -AsJob
Wait-Job $myjob
$received = Receive-Job $myjob
$received
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ranadip - How will that possible work in real time (as it waits for the job to complete...

Imagine a simple scriptblock that outputs a line, then waits 5 minutes, then outputs a second line, then exits...

The goal is to see the first line that is output "immediately" even though the job will run for another 5 minutes!

Comment: Then dont wait-job in the next line. Skip that line. Then use a do while loop with the status check and sleep and finally you receive the job using receive-job. Makes sense ?